# How to insert local time with mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

Have a shared server and running a mysql trigger in which time is being inserted into a column as follows -

```
Insert INTO mytable SET time=now();
```

The table and the column `time` then gets a GMT time.

I want that local time is inserted into that table and column.

Tried this code but still giving GMT time on insertion -

```
set @localtime = CONVERT_TZ('now()','GMT','+5:30');

Insert INTO mytable SET time=@localtime;
```

The column `time` has settings of TIMESTAMP as default and if I change the settings to Varchar, it gives error - "#1048 - Column 'time' cannot be null"

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried replacing 'GMT' with '+0:00' ? Other alternatives might be to set the server local TZ directly https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: @Joshua Already tried '+0:00 ' but gives same result. As I told I am on a shared server, so cannot change server local time directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to this question -

```
set @localtime = (SELECT CONVERT_TZ('now()','@@session.time_zone','+5:30'));

Insert INTO mytable SET time=@localtime;
```